# Automatic parsing of the test report

Tags: python, automation, nlp, automated-tests, artificial-intelligence

I have a Python Test Suite that dump the logs in text and html format. But the logs analysis is taking more than hour every day to validate the failures.

Is it possible to automate this task that can summarize the failures and check if these failure are same as the previous run or new failures?

Some kind of basic AI framework or Text analysis tool that can remember and summarize the results.

I tried to google around these requirements but I couldn't find something that help me jump on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be able to do is create a set of regular expressions to parse the output file. For example, if your logfile has syntax like:

```
...results are here...
...results are here...
...results are here...
...results are here...
ERROR: This test failed for X reason...
WARNING: This is dangerous because Y...
```

Then you could write a function to match that syntax using regular expressions.

You could get the number of errors quite easily, and depending on your format, you will probably be able to get the error or warning messages fairly easily as well. Then you could create a WARNING class or an ERROR class to keep track of these errors and warnings. If errors tend to be similar, or the same errors occur frequently, this should be

[Here is a link to the documentation for re in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Thanks @statsman. How do I keep record of this data for certain period so that the report analysis script can indicate when was the last time a particular issue occurred. Do you suggest a data base or a simple xls/csv file will work?

Comment: @PYN I would suggest keeping a new logfile, not necessarily xls/csv. But every time the parser runs, it could dump a timestamp and some info about the errors into a text file. You could set up a database, but unless your task is incredibly complex, it would probably be easier to just ctrl-f in the text file your parser creates.

Answer (score 0):

You can you nearest neighbour algorithm like [KNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) for text analysis, these can help you to detect similar possible issue. If you storing logs into [Open Search then it support KNN queries as well](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/knn/knn-index/).

If you like to hack and build more customize solution then I would like to suggest [Haystack](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack) for this task.

Disclaimer: I am community maintainer of Haystack.